# Parse delimited csv file using Python, output to terminal or file

Tags: python, parsing, csv

I have been working on a Python script to parse a single delimited column in a csv file. However, the column has multiple different delimiters and I can't figure out how to do this.

I have another script that works on similar data, but can't get this one to work. The data below is in a single column on the row. I want to have the script parse these out and add tabs in between each. Then I want to append this data into a list with only the unique items. Typically I am dealing with several hundred rows of this data and would like to parse the entire file and then return only the unique items in two columns (one for IP and other for URL).

Data to parse: 123.123.123.123::url.com,url2.com,234.234.234.234::url3.com (note ":" and "," are used as delimiters on the same line)

Script I am working with:

```
import sys
import csv

csv_file = csv.DictReader(open(sys.argv[1], 'rb'), delimiter=':')

uniq_rows = []

for column in csv_file:
    X = column[' IP'].split(':')[-1]
    row = X + '\t' 

    if row not in uniq_rows:
        uniq_rows.append(row)

for row in uniq_rows:
    print row
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: is :: one delimiter or two ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the list (`uniq_rows = []`) to a set (`uniq_rows = set()`):

```
csv_file = csv.DictReader(open(sys.argv[1], 'rU'), delimiter=':')
uniq_rows = set()
for column in csv_file:
    X = column[' IP'].split(':')[-1]
    row = X + '\t' 
    uniq_rows.add(row)

for row in list(uniq_rows):
    print row
```

If you need further help, leave a comment

Comment: I made the change, but still can't parse the file. I am getting an error on the "split" line.

Comment: My end goal is to have lots of rows like:


123.123.123.123::url.com,url2.com,234.234.234.234::url3.com 
123.123.123.123::url.com,url2.com,234.234.234.234::url3.com 
123.123.123.123::url.com,url2.com,234.234.234.234::url3.com 


And to parse that data into: 


123.123.123.123        url.com 
                       url2.com 
234.234.234.234        url3.com 


Note that url2.com didn't have an IP associated with it

Comment: Error is 

file.py", line 10, in <module>
    for column in csv_file:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 103, in next
    self.fieldnames
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 90, in fieldnames
    self._fieldnames = self.reader.next()
_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?

Comment: @user341087 Are you opening the file in universal-newline mode?

Comment: You aren't... I've edited my solution to use universal line mode

Answer (score 0):

you can also just use replace to change your import lines: (not overly pythonic I guess but standard builtin):

```
>>> a = "123.123.123.123::url.com,url2.com,234.234.234.234::url3.com"
>>> a = a.replace(',','\t')
>>> a = a.replace(':','\t')
>>> print (a)
123.123.123.123     url.com url2.com    234.234.234.234     url3.com
>>>
```

as mentioned in comment here a simple text manipulation to get you (hopefully) the right output prior to cleaning non duplicates:

```
import sys

read_raw_file = open('D:filename.csv') # open current file
read_raw_text  = read_raw_file.read()
new_text = read_raw_text.strip()

new_text = new_text.replace(',','\t')
# new_text = new_text.replace('::','\t') optional if you want double : to only include one column
new_text = new_text.replace(':','\t')

text_list = new_text.split('\n')
unique_items = []
for row in text_list:
    if row not in unique_items:
        unique_items.append(row)


new_file ='D:newfile.csv'
with open(new_file,'w') as write_output_file: #generate new file
    for i in range(0,len(unique_items)):
        write_output_file.write(unique_items[i]+'\n')
    write_output_file.close()
```

Comment: True, but I could also just use the delimiter feature in excel and dedupe that way as well...I am just trying to automate this and make is faster.